# With LFTP How do I send a specific file to server overwriting if it exists?

Tags: lftp

I'm building an production site update script using expect and lftp.

I'm trying for sometime to do this simple thing: send a file overwriting if it exists. But I just can't find a command that allow me to overwrite destination on put. put -c just continues if it's the same file. But if it's different it does nothing.

Do I really have to check if the file exists and delete it in order to put the file in the server ? isn't there a direct command ?

If that's the only option, then there's another thing I couldn't find: a command to see if the file exists. My only option is to treat ls's output ?

I also accept recommendations if there's another ftp client that allows me to do these things in an easier manner.

Comment: a regular FTP PUT should overwrite the remote file with local by default, innit?

Comment: Doesn't overwrite in the server I'm using. Tested it.Just to see if had done something wrong last week, I retested it right now. Doesn't overwrite.

Comment: `put -e` should overwrite and remove the file prior to upload.  Make sure you use a **lowercase** `e` as an uppercase `E` would actually remove from your local system.  See the [LFTP man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LFTP offers a parameter for `put` which is a lowercase `e`.

This allows you to remove the file before uploading it, as opposed to an overwrite option (which LFTP doesn't appear to inherently support).  Things like `prompt` could be available, but if we're strictly discussing LFTP, I would recommend using that option, ala:

`put -e file.txt`

[From the LFTP man pages.](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)

Comment: This page is inaccessible from my company's internal network and LFTP's console help doesn't list this option. Thanks. That was what I needed. The reward is yours :) I can only award the reward after 24 hours. After that period I'll give it to you.